# Age is not getting calculated correctly?

Tags: javascript

```
function getAge(dateString1,dateString2) {
    var today = new Date(dateString2);
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString1);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

I know it's kind of riddle, but I know this function is producing faulty results about but Not sure when it will?
DateString are std. date object in JavaScript.

```
Input On which it produced faulty results 
DateString1
1988-04-05 00:00:00
1965-05-06 00:00:00
1971-03-14 00:00:00
1975-11-10 00:00:00
1981-10-21 00:00:00
1974-06-01 00:00:00
1988-08-11 00:00:00

DateString2
2016-03-31 00:00:00
```

After evaluation age must never come >=65, but for these values it was not the case.

Comment: What case is it faulty? All of them? What does that >=65 line have to do with the code?

Comment: yes all of them. Well basically I was passing these 2 dates and age was supposed to be less than 65 always. But for these cases calculated age was either > or = to 65

Comment: When I run your code, none of these cases return an age >= 65.

Comment: Same here. When I run your code, it seems to perform correctly.

Comment: How is this function getting called? Can you show some more code? I assume the inputs are faulty.

Comment: Yes @AndersTornblad see the update

Comment: Your edit will probably be rejected, because you are using two different StackOverflow identities - one for asking the question and another for editing. Don't do that. It makes your edit look like a conflicting edit, or a faulty attempt at answering. But it seems you are calling your function with bad `Date` objects. Your function requires `string` input - not `Date` input!

Comment: I didn't do that intentionally, I forgot my login so I made an account with gmail. But after that I logged in from original account. If it violates SO policy I will remove  the other account. My intentions are not bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply display the age as completed years, this is a nice hack for doing it:

```
function getAgeInFullYears(birthdate, today) {
    // These two lines are not necessary if function is called with proper Date objects
    birthdate = new Date(birthdate);
    today = new Date(today);

    birthdate = birthdate.getFullYear() * 10000 +
                birthdate.getMonth() * 100 +
                birthdate.getDate();

    today = today.getFullYear() * 10000 +
            today.getMonth() * 100 +
            today.getDate();

    return Math.floor((today - birthdate) / 10000);
}
```

It works by "converting" dates to decimal numbers in the form of yyyymmdd, like 19,740,427 for April 27 1974. It then subtracts the birth date from the current date, divides the result with 10000 and skips the remainder.

The factors 100 and 10000 used are actually pretty arbitrary, and any factors work as long as the month factor is >= 31 and the year factor is >= (12 * month factor).

Calling `getAgeInFullYears('1988-04-05', '2016-02-18')` returns 27, for example.